# How to combine 2 tables into one table and sum the price if the item code are the same in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, group-by, sum

[image]

Hi everyone,

I want to combine Table 1 and Table 2 into one table (Table 3). If the Item Code 1 and Item code 2 are the same, then sum the price. The final output should be something like Table 3. I'm not sure whether this can be done without VBA or not, preferably not using VBA. However, VBA is still fine if there is no way for excel function to perform this grouping task. Any advice will be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: The easiest way to build a scalable solution would be to use [Power Query](https://www.excelcampus.com/powerquery/power-query-combine-tables/)

Comment: Please, test the code I posted. It creates a new table, based on the above described logic, on the same sheet, one column distance from the second table, on the same row of the first table...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next code:

```
Sub JoinTables()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, T1 As ListObject, T2 As ListObject, T3 As ListObject
  Dim arr1, arr2, arr3, arrHead, dict As Object, i As Long, iRow As Long, iCol As Long
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the necessary sheet
  Set T1 = sh.ListObjects("Table1") 'use here your first table name
  Set T2 = sh.ListObjects(2)        'use here your second table name
  
  arr1 = T1.DataBodyRange.Value     'put the data body range in an array
  arr2 = T2.DataBodyRange.Value
  arrHead = T1.HeaderRowRange.Value 'put thea header in an array
  
  Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'create a dictionary
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr1)
    dict(arr1(i, 1)) = arr1(i, 2) 'input all in the dictionary
  Next i
  
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr2)  'process the second table, too
    If Not dict.Exists(arr2(i, 1)) Then
        dict(arr2(i, 1)) = arr2(i, 2) 'create a new key
    Else
        dict(arr2(i, 1)) = dict(arr2(i, 1)) + arr2(i, 2) 'add to the existing key
    End If
  Next i

  'interesting way of obtaining an array by other (one column) arrays combination:
  arr3 = Application.Transpose(Array(dict.Keys, dict.Items)) 'combine the two array !!!

  iRow = T1.HeaderRowRange.row 'the row where the new Table will be created
  iCol = T2.HeaderRowRange.Column + T2.HeaderRowRange.Columns.count 'column of the new table

  sh.Range(sh.cells(iRow, iCol + 1), sh.cells(iRow, iCol + 2)).Value = arrHead 'put the header
  sh.cells(iRow, iCol + 1).Offset(1).Resize(UBound(arr3), UBound(arr3, 2)).Value = arr3 'put the content
  sh.cells(iRow, iCol + 1).CurrentRegion.Select 'select it to become a table in the next code line

  Set T3 = sh.ListObjects.Add  'create the new table
  'Copy the second column format in the new created table
  T3.DataBodyRange.Columns(2).NumberFormat = T1.DataBodyRange.Columns(2).NumberFormat
End Sub
```

**Edited** to ad a version working with ranges:

```
Sub MergeRanges()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR1 As Long, lastR2 As Long, firstCol1 As Long, firstCol2 As Long
  Dim arr1, arr2, arr3, arrHead, dict As Object, i As Long, iRow As Long, iCol As Long
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the necessary sheet
  firstCol1 = 7: firstCol2 = 10 'where are the first column of the two ranges
  iRow = 14                     ' the row where the header is
  
  lastR1 = sh.cells(rows.count, firstCol1).End(xlUp).row
  lastR2 = sh.cells(rows.count, firstCol2).End(xlUp).row
  
  arr1 = sh.Range(sh.cells(iRow + 1, firstCol1), sh.cells(lastR1, firstCol1 + 1)).Value 'put the range in an array
  arr2 = sh.Range(sh.cells(iRow + 1, firstCol2), sh.cells(lastR2, firstCol2 + 1)).Value
  arrHead = sh.Range(sh.cells(iRow, firstCol1), sh.cells(iRow, firstCol1 + 1)).Value  'put thea header in an array
  
  Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'create a dictionary
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr1)
    dict(arr1(i, 1)) = arr1(i, 2) 'input all in the dictionary
  Next i
  
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr2)
    If Not dict.Exists(arr2(i, 1)) Then
        dict(arr2(i, 1)) = arr2(i, 2) 'create a new key
    Else
        dict(arr2(i, 1)) = dict(arr2(i, 1)) + arr2(i, 2) 'add to the existing key
    End If
  Next i
  
  arr3 = Application.Transpose(Array(dict.Keys, dict.Items)) 'combine the two array !!!

  iCol = firstCol2 + 3 'column of the new table
  
  sh.Range(sh.cells(iRow, iCol + 1), sh.cells(iRow, iCol + 2)).Value = arrHead 'put the header
  With sh.cells(iRow, iCol + 1).Offset(1).Resize(UBound(arr3), UBound(arr3, 2))
    .Value = arr3 'put the content
    .Columns(2).NumberFormat = sh.cells(iRow + 1, firstCol1 + 1).NumberFormat
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, I copy your code and run it in my VBA editor, it shows me that "invalid outside procedure"

Comment: @weizer: Did you copy it in a standard module? On which line does the error appear? Did you adapt the code **to use your real tables**, as I recommended?

Comment: I think the problem is `sh.ListObjects("Table1)` and  `sh.ListObjects(2)`? Because I didn't define my table, so the name for the table doesn't work. Which part of the code I need to change to adapt my situation? Your code looks too advance and complicated to me.

Comment: @weizer: But it should be obvious, I thought... Use instead "Table1" the name of your first table, and instead on 2 the name of your second table. I used (2), because I couldn't name my second table "Table2". Such a name alerady existed in my test environment workbook. And I thought that it is not mandatory that your tables to be named "Table1" and "Table2". If you have only two tables in the active sheet, you can use (1) and (2)...

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! The problem is that my table is not really a table in excel, it is just 2 column combine into a "table". Your method require me to define it as a Table (Ctrl + T). Sorry if I confuse you in my question.

Comment: I also realized that when I run the code again (new data come in in Table 1 and Table 2), there is a bug mentioning that the table cannot be overlap. Seems like the code create a table instead of replace the existing one.

Comment: @weizer: Of course you confused us... It is a little simpler to process only two ranges, but I do not have time to make another code. Maybe later... Before asking a question, it is recomendable to at least know the difference between a table and a range.

Comment: @weizer: You are annoying, no offence... Who said something about replacing of something? Did you say that and I missed it? When you are talking about Table1, Table2 and Table3, which does not exist, of course it must be created. And how to overlap them if Table1 is first, followed by Table2? The third table is created one column after the second table. How did you create them? Do you have the second one in front of the first? Can you show as a picture, at least?

Comment: @weizer: Can you tell us, at least, on which columns are the two pseudo tables, on which rows their headers are and on which columns do you like the third 'table' to be created?

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time. I just want to combine column D6:E10 and column G6:H12 into one column for Item code and one column for price. So if the item code is the same, just sum the price. The output can be anywhere and not necessary required a header since I can manually type the header. When there is new data in D11:E11, the code able to include the new data as well.

Comment: @weizer: I prepared an updated piece of code working with ranges. You should choose the first column of the first range (4 in your case), the first column of the second range (7 in your case) and the row of headers (6 in your case). It returns the new created range a column after the second existing. Meaning it will start from "J6". The code can be adapted to return where you need, but it would be good to try it by yourself. If no succes, I will help you with this part, too. The code calculates the last row of each pseudo table (range), so you can add as many elements you need.

Comment: @weizer: Pasting below the existing range can be done, but it should not be recommended, since it allows the existing range to receive new records...

Comment: @weizer: Anyhow the processing result can not be pasted in D11:E11. It may start form D11, but goes down as many elements have been detected by the code...

Comment: Thanks FaneDuru! It works perfectly for me. Sorry for being not clear in my question before.

Comment: @weizer: Glad I (finally) could help! Please tace more care when post a new question and try putting in the skin of the one reading it. We are not the mind readers...

Answer (score 0):

Simple `SUMIF()` can give you desired output. Try-

```
=SUMIF($B$4:$B$13,H4,$C$4:$C$13)+SUMIF($E$4:$E$13,H4,$F$4:$F$13)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Harun24HR, thanks for your input. I'm sorry if I didn't make the question clear. I cannot reference the cells in column H because Table 3 is empty. So the function or the VBA code need to be able to filter the item code in Table 1 and Table 2. Just imagine that there is no Table 3 and I need to create my own Table 3

Comment: Oh! Then you need `VBA` or `Power Query`.